# PHP curl login too long

Tags: php, authentication, curl, digest

I have a web-service that I can use with my browser but cannot call with CURL in a PHP script.

Here the code I use with an example of the login/password sent.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_DIGEST);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD,'BmN+GP4VBev5tVzJU/altsyXXw0PXYcunbT8F8EatlbpctBXZp1OO2ySQyekZb5729qQPkdwdDBoUxMjBu1mlvv5Bt90GGRwyvEHGTMlT9cjs5YRpBJxEhksVyoL1Z4pwLAq3gKSj+PGW0HQhOSr8h7lyMG+9HJjL7pKeeds+Byn+TYnaium1MsGFg4TiE6Ztvr6rVpdaJSI3einSABuC1PCnNPkbHEdtwdrd8DU2jKcQ1fzderhmuJQE6pls6wwQjWF6sCTUTo/upUHUe0p5GY+7pKCHBXgNEhRhx3JgweiJN8ErxoiPCCIOdOScAEfcgZOgqQDGsJqnhuQ/5fKqg==:passwordOfTheUser');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
var_export(curl_getinfo($ch))."\n";
```

If I look at the content of the getInfo, I got this

```
[...]
'request_header' => 'GET /uriNotRelevant.queryString=Data HTTP/1.1
Authorization: Digest     username="BmN+GP4VBev5tVzJU/altsyXXw0PXYcunbT8F8EatlbpctBXZp1OO2ySQyekZb5729qQPkdwdDBoUxMjBu1mlvv5Bt90GGRwyvEHGTMlT9cjs5YRpBJxEhksVyoL1Z4pwLAq3gKSj+PGW0HQhOSr8h7lyMG+9HJjL7pKeeds+Byn+TYnaium1MsGFg4TiE6Ztvr6rVpdaJSI3einSABuC1PCnNPkbHEdtwdrd8DU2jKcQ1fzderhmuJQE6pls6w", realm="SVCCompagnonRelay Digest Authentication", nonce="MTM1NDQ4Nzc2NjkzNjoxYTRhMThkOTk5Yjc4OWY1Y2Q0MWQ3NzY3NzRlYzFlYw==", uri="/uriNotRelevant.queryString=Data", cnonce="MTczNDU1", nc=00000001, qop="auth", response="c319b14a40bf54955b764117d7f4bbc3"
Host: example.org
Accept: */*
Cookie: MBLPRDSession=C7B717115F119BAAB5C5BC308DD7FB18; WASMBLPRD2AND=mbltrap21and

',
)
```

You can see that the header that contain the login:password is truncated.
I tried to set the Header manualy, but reproduce the DIGEST protocole is harder that thought

I don't know what to do now :-(

Do you have any idea how to enlarge digest login size ?

**Edit² :**
fixed the problem, see my solution

Answer (score 0):

I search into the source code of CURL and found this :

```
//http_digets.c
#define MAX_VALUE_LENGTH 256
#define MAX_CONTENT_LENGTH 1024
```

```
//urldata.c
#define MAX_CURL_USER_LENGTH 256
#define MAX_CURL_PASSWORD_LENGTH 256
#define MAX_CURL_USER_LENGTH_TXT "255"
#define MAX_CURL_PASSWORD_LENGTH_TXT "255"
```

Maybe this is why my header is truncated by 256 chars. I will try to re-compile curl with a higher value and see if it fix the problem.

I changed data of urldata.c to 4096 and 4095 (yest it's big) and it worked very nice. I fixed my problem in PHP.
I created another problem, I canot use curl in commande line

```
#curl http://google.fr
curl: (2) Failed initialization
```

but even without changing anything i have this problem. It is not related to my modification. Maybe the version is too updated (last one) for my system. This is another question. Anyway, I do not use it in commande line on my webservers.